# Cannot get external file properties loaded in Context

Tags: spring, properties-file

I'm setting up a project using Spring 3.2.9.FINAL and I'm just unable to load some properties I've stored in an external file. That's how my application-context.xml looks:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="file:/home/myapp/settings.properties" />

    <bean class="foo.Test">
        <property name="property" value="${test.property}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

That's the content of my `settings.properties` file:

```
test.property=Hello world
```

The `foo.Test` class is very simple and only contains a String property. In my main method I do this:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory dlbf = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(dlbf);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource(
                "/application-context.xml", Test.class));
        System.out.println(dlbf.getBean(Test.class).getProperty());
    }
}
```

That's what I get when executing it:

```
Jun 12, 2014 12:03:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
${test.property}
```

I tried several workarounds based in answers from SO, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the content of `/home/myapp/settings.properties`?

Comment: Just `test.property=Hello world`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading beans into a `BeanFactory` whereas you should use an `ApplicationContext`.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx d= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(Test.class).getProperty());
    }
}
```

See [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory) for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks mate! Please remove the extra variable declaration from the third line ;-)

Comment: ApplicationContext does not support lazy loading.  BeanFactory supports lazy loading.

Comment: @AmrishPandey An `ApplicationContext` is `BeanFactory` and it uses a `BeanFactory` internally. Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Application context loads all beans from spring XML file and doesn't support selective lazy loading but using XML bean factory version (check precise class name ) one can selectively load beans. Please test.

Comment: @AmrishPandey no it doesn't and as mentioned it doesn't make sense what you say...

Answer (score 0):

Application context loads all beans from spring XML file and doesn't support selective lazy loading but using XML bean factory version (check precise class name ) one can selectively load beans. Please test.